# MVC 4/5 - C# - 2 ways encryption for query string value

Tags: c#, encryption, model-view-controller

I have a problem, I need to encrypt/decrypt an integer value and pass it with an url to a query string.

Instead of doing 'www.mysite/user/id'  i want to do 'www.mysite/user/encrypted_value_of_id'

And of course I need to decrypt the value.

I need a basic simple straight forward url friendly encryption nothing fancy. I tried several samples, different encryption methods, but nothing worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A question to ponder: Is an encrypted ID really any different from an ID? After all, it's still a unique ID, right?

That aside, here's a little something I use when I need to encrypt stuff that round-trips to the client:

```
public static class MachineKeyEncryptionExtensions
{
    private static ThreadLocal<BinaryFormatter> formatterPool = 
          new ThreadLocal<BinaryFormatter>(() => new BinaryFormatter());

    public static string Encrypt(this object rci)
    {
        byte[] data;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatterPool.Value.Serialize(ms, rci);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        var ba=MachineKey.Protect(data, "encrypted data");
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ba);
    }
    public static T Decrypt<T>(this string encrypted)
    {
        var ba = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
        var decodedArr=MachineKey.Unprotect(ba, "encrypted data");
        object o;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(decodedArr))
        {
            o = formatterPool.Value.Deserialize(ms);
        }

        return (T)o;

    }
    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        int numberChars = hex.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[numberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberChars; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return bytes;
    }
    public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
    {
        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
        return hex.Replace("-", "");
    }

}
```